# How to send an email from inside application in Unity?

Tags: c#, email, unity-game-engine

I want my application to send email from inside the application. Currently using the code below in sending email but it opens my email app first before sending.

public void EmailUs () 
    {

```
    //email Id to send the mail to
    string email = "test@gmail.com";
    //subject of the mail
    string subject = MyEscapeURL("INQUIRY");
    //body of the mail which consists of Device Model and its Operating System
    string body = "";
    int k = 1;
    do {
        body = MyEscapeURL ("Please Enter your message here\n\n\n\n" +
        "________" +

        Application.OpenURL ("mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body);
    } while(k != num);

}  

string MyEscapeURL (string url) 
{
    return WWW.EscapeURL(url).Replace("+","%20");
}
```

is it possible to send email from inside the application without opening mail? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already and take a look at [ask]. The first point there is "Search, and research", you don't show much research effort. If you use `Application.OpenURL` and start with "mailto:", you'll always automatically open the email app. Have you tried to do this differently?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, here is a script that should do the job!

```
private MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

void SendEmails()
{
    mail.From = new MailAddress("GIVE_YOUR_EMAIL_HERE");
    mail.To.Add("GIVE_YOUR_DESTINATION_HERE");

    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("GIVE_SMTP_INFO_HERE");
    smtpServer.Port = 587;//GIVE CORRECT PORT HERE
    mail.Subject = "WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TEXT";
    mail.Body = "WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TEXT";
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("GIVE_SMTP_INFO_HERE", "GIVE_YOUR_EMAIL_PASSWORD_HERE") as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    { return true; };
    smtpServer.Send(mail);
    //smtpServer.SendAsync(mail)
    Debug.Log("success");
}
```

Comment: I do not remember, I did this a year ago but i believe not.

Comment: @Janella You will, of course, need to supply some SMPT details (`GIVE_SMTP_INFO_HERE` is hardly a server name). If you don't have a server, or if the one you have won't accept the email and actually send it, check out a service like Mail Chimp

Comment: I added `GIVE_SMTP_INFO_HERE` so it could be replaced with the SMTP server i.e. _smtp.myemail.com_

Comment: I only tested on android, so yea. Oh and maybe iOS as well but I am not 100% sure